# Why is Google DNS server not returning authoritative answer for itself

Tags: dns, bind

Why is the Google DNS server not returning an authoritative answer for its own domain ?

I am using `nslookup` and `dig` under Redhat Linux 5.1 with Bind DNS v4.9.7.

### Test

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 0
search home
```

/etc/named.boot:

```
...
options         forward-only query-log
forwarders      192.168.1.1 203.12.160.35 203.12.160.36 203.12.160.37
...
```

Querying IP address of "dns.google.com" (using my DNS server):

```
[root@r51 ~]$ date && nslookup dns.google.com
Sat Jan 13 22:34:31 EST 2024
Server:  r51
Address:  0.0.0.0

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    dns.google.com
Addresses:  8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8

[root@r51 ~]$
[root@r51 ~]$ date && dig dns.google.com
Sat Jan 13 22:36:15 EST 2024

; <<>> DiG 2.2 <<>> dns.google.com
;; res options: init recurs defnam dnsrch
;; got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6
;; flags: qr rd ra; Ques: 1, Ans: 2, Auth: 0, Addit: 0
;; QUESTIONS:
;;      dns.google.com, type = A, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:
dns.google.com. 210     A       8.8.8.8
dns.google.com. 210     A       8.8.4.4

;; Total query time: 15 msec
;; FROM: r51 to SERVER: default -- 0.0.0.0
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 13 22:36:15 2024
;; MSG SIZE  sent: 32  rcvd: 64

[root@r51 ~]$
```

Querying IP address of "dns.google.com" (using "dns.google.com"):

```
[root@r51 ~]$ date && nslookup dns.google.com 8.8.8.8
Sat Jan 13 22:36:20 EST 2024
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    dns.google.com
Addresses:  8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8

[root@r51 ~]$
[root@r51 ~]$ date && dig @8.8.8.8 dns.google.com
Sat Jan 13 22:36:42 EST 2024

; <<>> DiG 2.2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 dns.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; res options: init recurs defnam dnsrch
;; got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10
;; flags: qr rd ra; Ques: 1, Ans: 2, Auth: 0, Addit: 0
;; QUESTIONS:
;;      dns.google.com, type = A, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:
dns.google.com. 900     A       8.8.8.8
dns.google.com. 900     A       8.8.4.4

;; Total query time: 12 msec
;; FROM: r51 to SERVER: 8.8.8.8
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 13 22:36:42 2024
;; MSG SIZE  sent: 32  rcvd: 64

[root@r51 ttya3 22:36:42 /]$
```

### Result

Expected (ie. query against 8.8.8.8):

```
Auth: 1
```

Actual:

```
Non-authoritative answer

Auth: 0
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about UNIX/Linux

Comment: Why would they provide authoritative answers? The authoritative nameservers for `google.com` are `ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com`,  and since there is no separate `NS` record for `dns.google.com`, only those DNS servers will be returning authoritative answers for `dns.google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @muru's comment, the reason it doesn't work is because 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (dns.google.com) are not authoritative name servers.

Authoritative name servers can be obtained for a domain by querying its SOA record and then using the origin name server (detailed in the record) as the reference server in subsequent DNS queries:

```
nslookup -type=soa dns.google.com

dig soa dns.google.com
```

Example SOA query output:

```
[root@r51 ~]$ nslookup -type=soa dns.google.com
Server:  r51
Address:  0.0.0.0

Authoritative answers can be found from:
google.com
        origin = ns1.google.com
        mail addr = dns-admin.google.com
        serial = 598133582
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 1800 (30 mins)
        minimum ttl = 60 (1 min)
[root@r51 ~]$
[root@r51 ~]$ dig soa dns.google.com

; <<>> DiG 2.2 <<>> soa dns.google.com
;; res options: init recurs defnam dnsrch
;; got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6
;; flags: qr rd ra; Ques: 1, Ans: 0, Auth: 1, Addit: 0
;; QUESTIONS:
;;      dns.google.com, type = SOA, class = IN

;; AUTHORITY RECORDS:
google.com.     60      SOA     ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. (
                        597792727       ; serial
                        900     ; refresh (15 mins)
                        900     ; retry (15 mins)
                        1800    ; expire (30 mins)
                        60 )    ; minimum (1 min)

;; Total query time: 108 msec
;; FROM: r51 to SERVER: default -- 0.0.0.0
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 31 10:08:09 2023
;; MSG SIZE  sent: 32  rcvd: 82

[root@r51 ~]$
```

The above SOA queries show that an authoritative server can be found at "ns1.google.com".

Querying IP address of "dns.google.com" (using authoritative name server):

```
[root@r51 ~]$ nslookup dns.google.com ns1.google.com
Server:  ns1.google.com
Address:  216.239.32.10

Name:    dns.google.com
Addresses:  8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8

[root@r51 ~]$
[root@r51 ~]$ dig @ns1.google.com dns.google.com

; <<>> DiG 2.2 <<>> @ns1.google.com dns.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; res options: init recurs defnam dnsrch
;; got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10
;; flags: qr aa rd; Ques: 1, Ans: 2, Auth: 0, Addit: 0
;; QUESTIONS:
;;      dns.google.com, type = A, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:
dns.google.com. 900     A       8.8.4.4
dns.google.com. 900     A       8.8.8.8

;; Total query time: 113 msec
;; FROM: r51 to SERVER: ns1.google.com  216.239.32.10
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 13 23:54:03 2024
;; MSG SIZE  sent: 32  rcvd: 64

[root@r51 ~]$
```

As can be seen above, `nslookup` no longer displays `Non-authoritative answer` in the response.

As for `dig` output, the `Auth` value (in this case `Auth: 0`) indicates that authoritative *section* information was -not- printed (perhaps none was offered by the name server). However, the authoritative flag/bit is actually set  (ie. the `aa` in `flags: qr aa rd`).